# Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '([[Notice]?])'

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

How to decode list from Decoder in swift, when i am confirming to Decodable protocol

```
struct ActiveModuleRespones:Codable {
    var Notice:[Notice]?
    var Module:[Module]?


    public init(from: Decoder) throws {
        //decoding here
        let container = try from.singleValueContainer()
        self.Notice = try? container.decode([Notice].self)
    }

}
```

Getting this error :

```
Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '([[Notice]?])'
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Please help ,

Comment: First rule - class, struct, and enum names start with uppercase letters. Variable, method, and case names start with lowercase letters. Second rule - don't name a variable exactly the same as a type name. Too much confusion. Fix these issues and your code will be much better.

Comment: Omg!  i follow that rule but  in this class only , we are getting `Notice` and `Module` i'll try with custom key (CodingKeys) , thanks a lot for you comment @rmaddy

Answer (score 2):

It confused with the variable itself. Change the name of the variable to fix it.

```
struct ActiveModuleRespones: Codable {
    var notice: [Notice]?
    var module: [Module]?

    public init(from: Decoder) throws {
        //decoding here
        let container = try from.singleValueContainer()
        self.notice = try? container.decode([Notice].self)
    }
}
```

In Swift, all **types** have **UpperCamelCase** name and almost **anything else** have **lowerCamelCase** names.

Lastly, using `try?` will kill all exceptions and you will never know what is wrong, try using this instead:

```
self.notice = try container.decode([Notice]?.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need optional value use [`decodeIfPresent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2894339-decodeifpresent) with non-optional type and without `try?`

```
struct ActiveModuleRespones: Decodable {
    var notice: [Notice]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case notice
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.notice = try container.decodeIfPresent([Notice].self, forKey: .notice)
    }
}
```